# python - open wav file in default program (Linux)

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I want to open .wav file in default program. But it doesn´t work. This is my code:

```
audiofile=(myFile[index]+".wav") # I have all files in array (without ".wav") 

try:
    try:
        os.system('xdg-open audiofile')
    except:
        os.system('start audiofile')                    
except:
    print "error"
```

I don´t get any error, but it doesn´t work. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: If I type into terminal "xdg-open "path_to_audiofile", it works. But if I want to play audio from my python program, I get error. I don´t know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't substituting the name of the audio file into your OS commands, so it can't possibly work.

You'd need something like:

```
os.system('xdg-open ' + audiofile)
```

This assumes that you have a default application associated with `.wav` files, which of course you can test by trying your command manually.

You might also want to check the return value of `os.system` for an error code, rather than relying on exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should fill the variable `audiofile` into the command, not the string `'audiofile'` itself

```
os.system('xdg-open %s' % audiofile)
```

Second, 
`os.system` will NOT throw an exception when `xdg-open` or `start` doesn't exist in system.
Determine the type of system first by [platform.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.system)

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
```